# Module ‘”@prismicio/client”’ has no exported member ‘Content’ error on build on Vercel

Tags: typescript, prismic.io

I am on a Next.js project and when I run `npm run build`, I don't get any errors, but when my project is trying to get built on Vercel, I get the following error:

`Module '"@prismicio/client"' has no exported member 'Content'`

This error is odd because I can definitely see that the file has that exported `Content` namespace.

According to the [prismic docs][1], the way I am importing the types is correct, and since it works locally just fine, I wonder if there is something I need to be adding on Vercel to make this happen.

This is how I am using that in one of my files:

```
import { Content } from '@prismicio/client'
```

This is my `tsconfig.json` file contents:

```json
{
   "compilerOptions": {
      "baseUrl": ".",
      "target": "es6",
      "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext"],
      "allowJs": true,
      "skipLibCheck": true,
      "strict": false,
      "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
      "noEmit": true,
      "incremental": true,
      "esModuleInterop": true,
      "module": "esnext",
      "moduleResolution": "node",
      "resolveJsonModule": true,
      "isolatedModules": true,
      "jsx": "preserve",
      "paths": {
         "@/*": ["./*"]
      }
   },
   "include": [
      "next-env.d.ts",
      "react-table-config.d.ts",
      "prismicio-types.d.ts",
      "**/*.ts",
      "**/*.tsx",
      "**/*.css",
      "**.*.js",
      "foundations/*.js",
      "components/*.js",
      "lib/tailwind/colors.js"
   ],
   "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}
```

This is my `package.json` file contents:

```json
{
   "name": "project-web",
   "private": true,
   "scripts": {
      "dev": "API_URL=api.sandbox.project-web.com next dev",
      "build": "next build",
      "export": "next export",
      "build:next": "next build && next export -o dist/",
      "start": "next start",
      "lint:next": "next lint",
      "lint": "eslint './**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}' --quiet",
      "lint:fix": "eslint './**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}' --fix --quiet",
      "slicemachine": "start-slicemachine",
      "format": "prettier --write .",
      "test": "jest",
      "analyze": "ANALYZE=true next build",
      "tailwind-config-viewer": "tailwind-config-viewer -o",
      "storybook": "storybook dev -p 6006",
      "build-storybook": "storybook build",
      "chromatic": "npx chromatic --project-token=chpt_1f9dca6e3c11f4e",
      "compile": "tsc"
   },
   "dependencies": {
      "@aws-sdk/client-s3": "^3.86.0",
      "@aws-sdk/s3-request-presigner": "^3.86.0",
      "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^6.1.1",
      "@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons": "^6.1.1",
      "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^6.1.1",
      "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome": "^0.1.18",
      "@knocklabs/react-notification-feed": "^0.8.4",
      "@metamask/onboarding": "^1.0.1",
      "@milkdown/core": "^6.4.1",
      "@milkdown/plugin-emoji": "^6.4.1",
      "@milkdown/plugin-listener": "^6.4.1",
      "@milkdown/plugin-menu": "^6.4.1",
      "@milkdown/plugin-tooltip": "^6.4.1",
      "@milkdown/preset-gfm": "^6.4.1",
      "@milkdown/prose": "^6.4.1",
      "@milkdown/react": "^6.4.1",
      "@milkdown/theme-tokyo": "^6.4.1",
      "@next/bundle-analyzer": "^13.4.2",
      "@popperjs/core": "^2.11.6",
      "@prismicio/client": "^7.0.1",
      "@prismicio/next": "^1.2.1",
      "@prismicio/react": "^2.6.2",
      "@prismicio/types": "^0.2.8",
      "@privy-io/react-auth": "^1.25.1",
      "@radix-ui/react-visually-hidden": "1.0.2",
      "@snapshot-labs/snapshot.js": "^0.4.18",
      "@web3-react/core": "^8.2.0",
      "axios": "^0.27.2",
      "body-scroll-lock": "^4.0.0-beta.0",
      "classnames": "^2.3.2",
      "cookie": "^0.5.0",
      "date-fns": "^2.29.2",
      "debounce": "^1.2.1",
      "ethers": "^5.6.5",
      "image-trace-loader": "^1.0.2",
```